# regular expression for string containing repetition of same alphabet

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regular expressions. I am looking for String which have only repeated characters like (aaa or bbb) from A to Z.

I am using `@"\b[a-z]{1}(.){1,}\b"` which is partially working. Not completely.
I would appreciate if anyone help me in this regard.
Thanks.

Comment: Please add example input, expected output and what the result of your current regex is for each example input.

Answer (score 2):

You could capture the first character in a capturing group (group 1).

Then make sure the rest of the string contains the same character as the character captured in group 1 by using a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to group 1 like `\1`:

[`\b([a-zA-Z])\1+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/t7EcQE/3)

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `([a-zA-Z])` Match an upper or lowercase character in the first capturing group
- `\1+` Repeat the first caturing group 1 or more times
- `\b` Word boundary